Health connect not returning data without google fit
So ive written the bellow code and im running it on my Android 14 but i dont seem to be able to get any data. As soon as i installed google fit as well thats when i got all the data. Can anyone tell why this is happening. I would like this to work without having to use Google fit. Is it the way i read the data or is it that i dont write al all? Should i be writting data when this starts?
package gr.hua.beam.utils

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient
import androidx.health.connect.client.aggregate.AggregateMetric
import androidx.health.connect.client.aggregate.AggregationResultGroupedByPeriod
import androidx.health.connect.client.permission.HealthPermission
import androidx.health.connect.client.records.*
import androidx.health.connect.client.request.AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest
import androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest
import androidx.health.connect.client.time.TimeRangeFilter
import gr.hua.beam.ui.model.DataRecord
import gr.hua.beam.ui.model.DataType
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.TimeZone

object HealthConnectUtils {
private var healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient? = null

val PERMISSIONS = setOf(
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(StepsRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(SleepSessionRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(DistanceRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(ExerciseSessionRecord::class),
    HealthPermission.getReadPermission(HeartRateRecord::class),
)

private val dateTimeFormatter: DateTimeFormatter =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")

fun checkForHealthConnectInstalled(context: Context): Int {
    val availabilityStatus =
        HealthConnectClient.getSdkStatus(context, "com.google.android.apps.healthdata")
    when (availabilityStatus) {
        HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE -> {
            Log.w("HealthConnectUtils", "Health Connect SDK is unavailable on this device.")
        }
        HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE_PROVIDER_UPDATE_REQUIRED -> {
            Log.w("HealthConnectUtils", "Health Connect SDK needs an update.")
        }
        HealthConnectClient.SDK_AVAILABLE -> {
            Log.i("HealthConnectUtils", "Health Connect SDK is available.")
            healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(context)
        }
    }
    return availabilityStatus
}

suspend fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
    val granted = healthConnectClient?.permissionController?.getGrantedPermissions()
    return granted?.containsAll(PERMISSIONS) == true
}

suspend fun readStepsForInterval(interval: Long): List<DataRecord> {
    return readAggregateDataForInterval(interval, DataType.STEPS, StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL)
}

suspend fun readDistanceForInterval(interval: Long): List<DataRecord> {
    return readAggregateDataForInterval(interval, DataType.DISTANCE, DistanceRecord.DISTANCE_TOTAL)
}

suspend fun readMinsForInterval(interval: Long): List<DataRecord> {
    return readAggregateDataForInterval(interval, DataType.MINS, ExerciseSessionRecord.EXERCISE_DURATION_TOTAL)
}

suspend fun readSleepSessionsForInterval(interval: Long): List<DataRecord> {
    val startTime: ZonedDateTime = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusDays(interval - 1)
    val sleepData = mutableListOf<DataRecord>()
    val response = healthConnectClient?.readRecords(
        ReadRecordsRequest(
            SleepSessionRecord::class,
            timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime.toLocalDateTime(), LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
        )
    )
    if (response != null) {
        if (response.records.isEmpty()) {
            sleepData.add(
                DataRecord(
                    metricValue = "No data",
                    dataType = DataType.SLEEP,
                    toDatetime = startTime.plusSeconds(1).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                    fromDatetime = startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter)
                )
            )
        } else {
            var totalSleepMinutes = 0L
            for (record in response.records) {
                totalSleepMinutes += Duration.between(record.startTime, record.endTime).toMinutes()
            }
            sleepData.add(
                DataRecord(
                    metricValue = totalSleepMinutes.toString(),
                    dataType = DataType.SLEEP,
                    toDatetime = response.records.last().endTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                    fromDatetime = response.records.first().startTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
                )
            )
        }
    } else {
        sleepData.add(
            DataRecord(
                metricValue = "No data",
                dataType = DataType.SLEEP,
                toDatetime = startTime.plusSeconds(1).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                fromDatetime = startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter)
            )
        )
    }
    Log.d("HealthConnectUtils", "Sleep Data: $sleepData")
    return sleepData
}

suspend fun readHeartRateForInterval(interval: Long): List<DataRecord> {
    val startTime: ZonedDateTime = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusDays(interval - 1)
    val response = healthConnectClient?.readRecords(
        ReadRecordsRequest(
            HeartRateRecord::class,
            timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime.toLocalDateTime(), LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
        )
    )
    val heartRateData = mutableListOf<DataRecord>()
    if (response != null && response.records.isNotEmpty()) {
        val heartRates = response.records.flatMap { it.samples }.map { it.beatsPerMinute }
        val averageHeartRate = if (heartRates.isNotEmpty()) heartRates.average() else 0.0
        heartRateData.add(
            DataRecord(
                metricValue = averageHeartRate.toInt().toString(),
                dataType = DataType.HEART_RATE,
                toDatetime = response.records.last().endTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                fromDatetime = response.records.first().startTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
            )
        )
    } else {
        heartRateData.add(
            DataRecord(
                metricValue = "No data",
                dataType = DataType.HEART_RATE,
                toDatetime = startTime.plusSeconds(1).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                fromDatetime = startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter)
            )
        )
    }
    Log.d("HealthConnectUtils", "Heart Rate Data: $heartRateData")
    return heartRateData
}

private suspend fun <T : Any> readAggregateDataForInterval(interval: Long, dataType: DataType, metric: AggregateMetric<T>): List<DataRecord> {
    val startTime: ZonedDateTime = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusDays(interval - 1)
    val endTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()).minusMinutes(1).plusSeconds(59)
    val response = healthConnectClient?.aggregateGroupByPeriod(
        AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest(
            metrics = setOf(metric),
            timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(), endTime.toLocalDateTime()),
            timeRangeSlicer = Period.ofDays(1)
        )
    )
    return parseAggregateResponse(response, startTime, endTime, dataType, metric)
}

private fun <T : Any> parseAggregateResponse(
    response: List<AggregationResultGroupedByPeriod>?,
    startTime: ZonedDateTime,
    endTime: ZonedDateTime,
    dataType: DataType,
    metric: AggregateMetric<T>
): List<DataRecord> {
    val data = mutableListOf<DataRecord>()
    if (response != null) {
        response.sortedBy { it.startTime }
        var trackTime = startTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
        for (dailyResult in response) {
            if (dailyResult.startTime.isAfter(trackTime)) {
                while (trackTime.isBefore(dailyResult.startTime)) {
                    data.add(
                        DataRecord(
                            metricValue = "No data",
                            dataType = dataType,
                            toDatetime = trackTime.toLocalDate().atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
                                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                            fromDatetime = if (trackTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(startTime.toLocalDate()))
                                startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else trackTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
                        )
                    )
                    trackTime = trackTime.plusDays(1)
                }
            }
            val totalValue = dailyResult.result[metric]
            data.add(
                DataRecord(
                    metricValue = (totalValue ?: "No data").toString(),
                    dataType = dataType,
                    toDatetime = dailyResult.endTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusSeconds(1).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                    fromDatetime = if (dailyResult.startTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(startTime.toLocalDate()))
                        startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else dailyResult.startTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
                )
            )
            trackTime = dailyResult.endTime
        }
        while (trackTime.isBefore(endTime.toLocalDateTime()) && Duration.between(trackTime, endTime).toMinutes() > 1) {
            data.add(
                DataRecord(
                    metricValue = "No data",
                    dataType = dataType,
                    toDatetime = if (trackTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(endTime.toLocalDate()))
                        endTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else trackTime.toLocalDate().atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
                        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter),
                    fromDatetime = if (trackTime.toLocalDate().isEqual(startTime.toLocalDate()))
                        startTime.format(dateTimeFormatter) else trackTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter)
                )
            )
            trackTime = trackTime.plusDays(1).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
        }
    }
    Log.d("HealthConnectUtils", "Parsed Data: $data")
    return data
}

suspend fun writeStepsData(context: Context, steps: Int, startTime: ZonedDateTime, endTime: ZonedDateTime) {
    val stepsRecord = StepsRecord(
        count = steps.toLong(),
        startTime = startTime.toInstant(),
        startZoneOffset = startTime.offset,
        endTime = endTime.toInstant(),
        endZoneOffset = endTime.offset
    )

    val response = healthConnectClient?.insertRecords(listOf(stepsRecord))

    if (response != null) {
        Log.d("HealthConnectUtils", "Steps data written successfully: $response")
    } else {
        Log.e("HealthConnectUtils", "Failed to write steps data.")
    }
}
}

Im calling this like that:
val requestPermissions =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(PermissionController.createRequestPermissionResultContract()) { granted ->
        if (granted.containsAll(HealthConnectUtils.PERMISSIONS)) {
            scope.launch {
                mins = HealthConnectUtils.readMinsForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                steps = HealthConnectUtils.readStepsForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                distance = HealthConnectUtils.readDistanceForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                sleepDuration = HealthConnectUtils.readSleepSessionsForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                heartRate = HealthConnectUtils.readHeartRateForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permissions are rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    when (HealthConnectUtils.checkForHealthConnectInstalled(context)) {
        HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Health Connect client is not available for this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        HealthConnectClient.SDK_UNAVAILABLE_PROVIDER_UPDATE_REQUIRED -> {
            showHealthConnectInstallPopup = true
        }

        HealthConnectClient.SDK_AVAILABLE -> {
            if (HealthConnectUtils.checkPermissions()) {
                mins = HealthConnectUtils.readMinsForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                steps = HealthConnectUtils.readStepsForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                distance = HealthConnectUtils.readDistanceForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                sleepDuration = HealthConnectUtils.readSleepSessionsForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
                heartRate = HealthConnectUtils.readHeartRateForInterval(interval).lastOrNull()?.metricValue ?: "N/A"
            } else {
                requestPermissions.launch(HealthConnectUtils.PERMISSIONS)
            }
        }
    }
}


What is the source of the steps data you are writing? You can only read data back from Health Connect if another app has written it in. In this case, it's likely that Google Fit is the app supplying the data being read back. You can test this with one of the many other apps compatible with Health Connect, some are listed here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/promotion_all__health_connect
